# String array regex - excluding separator pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

here is my use case.
I have a list of words or phrases and I need to have them in a string array but the string can potentially have anything in the string. Therefore I just came up with a very unlikely separator.
So the user can search for phrases in multiple way one of them being wildcard searches.

so lets say user searches for `"* * word * word"`, these cases are working fine as I process the string for a js regex type to something like the following `".*? .*? word .*? word"`.

```
// separator = |;|
finalized regex above: /(.*? .*? word .*? word)\|;\|/gm
```

This works well for me. In most tested use cases at the moment.

The problem is that in one test case is where a user puts in the following:

```
I * going * on *day
```

which translates into:

```
(I .*? going .*? on .*?day)\|;\|/gm
```

problem is that in the string array there is an entry in position 1 like so:

```
I love going swimming on tuesday|;|phrase2|;|phrase3|;|phrase4|;|I love friday|;|last phrase
```

so with the above I'm getting a match on:

```
I love going swimming on tuesday|;|phrase2|;|phrase3|;|phrase4|;|I love friday|;|
```

how can I adjust my regex to allow everything except my separator value?

update --

your right here is a better example of my issue

```
GOTHIC PEOPLE WAS HERE LAST NIGHT|;|SAD + WIFE = HAPPY|;|GOLDEN 12|;|
```

regex:

```
(GOTHIC .*? WAS HE.*?2)\|;\|
```

Technically I wasn't expecting this to match but with the trailing 2 it matches right at the end of the string. So I'm needing to know how to only get the matches before the |;|

regex reference: 
https://regex101.com/r/yOuNYt/1

// better example --- RE EXPLAINED

```
regex: GOTHIC .*? WAS HE.*?2(\|;\|)
```

The above matches everything. 
This is the result:

```
GOTHIC PEOPLE WAS HERE LAST NIGHT|;|SAD + WIFE = HAPPY|;|GOLDEN 12|;|
```

As the "HE.*?2" has a 2 at the end I'm not wanting any result. The only reason there is a result is because ".*?" matches everything just before the 2. I'm wanting the ".*?" to include everything so that I might be able to match something like this:

```
"GOTHIC PEOPLE WAS HERE LAST NIGHT TILL 2"
```

but NOT include the "|;|" chars in that search

Comment: In my environment I got `I love going swimming on tuesday|;|` as the only match, using this regex: `/(I .*? going .*? on .*?day)\|;\|/gm`

Comment: I've edited my anser

Comment: You have `2` in the regex just before `\|;\|` so your regex from start will match everything till it finds `2` which is at end just before `\|;\|` so it is bound to match the whole string. What did you expect to match and logically how?

Comment: @TheMan68 I cannot get your problem.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi yeah correct. I know why its matching but im wanting the regex to only check up to the |;| how to i get the regex to not allow the "|;|" in the search at all?